# Interactive quiz in Bash (Multiple Q's)

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm teaching an introductory Linux course and have abandoned the paper-based multiple-choice quizzes and have created interactive quizzes in Bash. My quiz script is functional, but kind of quick-and-dirty, and now I'm in the improvement phase and looking for suggestions.

First off, I'm *not* looking to automate the grading, which certainly simplifies things.

Currently, I have a different script file for each quiz, and the questions are hard-coded. That's obviously terrible, so I created a .txt file holding the questions, delimited by lines with "question 01" etc. I can loop through and use `sed -n "/^quest.*$i\$/,/^quest.*$(($i+1))\$/p"`, but this prints the delimiter lines. I can pipe through `sed "/^q/d"` or `head -n-1|tail -n+2` to get rid of them, but is there a better way?

Second issue: For questions where the answer is an actual command, I'm printing a `[user]$` prompt, but for short-answer, I'm using a `>`. In my text file, for each question, the last line is the prompt to use. Initially, I was thinking I could store the question in a variable and `|tail -1` it to get the prompt, but duh, when you store it it strips newlines. I want the cursor to immediately follow the prompt, so I either need to pass it to `read -p` or strip the final newline from the output. (Or create some marker in the file to differentiate between the `$` and `>` prompt.) One thought I had was to store each question in a separate file and just `cat` it to display it, making sure there was no newline at the end. That might be kind of a pain to maintain, but it would solve both problems. Thoughts?

Now to how I'm actually running the quiz. This is a Fedora 20 box, and I tried copying `bash` and setuid-ing it to me so that it would be able to read the quiz script that the students couldn't normally read, but I couldn't get that to work. After some trial and error, I ended up copying `touch` and setuid-ing it to me, then using that to create their answer file in a "submit" directory with an ACL so new files have o=w so they can write to their answer file (in the quiz with `>> echo`) but not read it back or access the directory. The only major loophole I see with this is that they can delete their file by name and start the quiz over with no record of having done so. Since I'm not doing any automatic grading, I'm not terribly concerned with the students being able to read the script file, although if I'm storing the questions separately, I suppose I could make a copy of `cat` and setuid it to read in files that they can't access.

Also, I realize that Bash is not the best choice for this, and learning the required simple input/output for Python or something better would not take much effort. Perhaps that's my next step.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider posting each part of the question separately (maybe also post your script for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)). Single problem questions make it easier to accept single answers, and it makes it easier for future readers to find the answer they're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You could use

```
sed -n "/^quest.*$i\$/,/^quest.*$(($i+1))\$/ { //!p }"
```

Here `//` repeats the last attempted pattern, which is the opening pattern in the first line of the range and the closing pattern for the rest.

...by the way, if you really want to do this with sed, you better be **damn** sure that `i` is a number, or you'll run into code injection problems.

2) You can store multiline command output in a variable without problems. You just have to make sure you quote the variable everafter to avoid shell expansion on it. For example,

```
QUESTION=$(sed -n "/^quest.*$i\$/,/^quest.*$(($i+1))\$/ { //!p }" questions.txt)
echo -n "$QUESTION"        # <-- the double quotes are important here.
```

The `-n` option to `echo` tells echo to not append a newline at the end, which should take care of your prompt problem.

3) Yes, well, hackery breeds more hackery. If you want to lock this down, the first order of business would be to not give students a shell on the test machine. You could put your script behind inetd and have the students fill it out with telnet or something, I suppose, but...really, why bash? If it were me, I'd knock something together with a web server and one of the several gazillion php web quiz frameworks. Although I also have to wonder why it's a problem if students can see the questions and the answers they gave. It's not like all students use the same account and can see each other's answers, is it? (is it?) Don't store an answer key on the same machine and you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Dude! Obviously I was thinking about `echo -n` but I had no idea that the quotes would retain newlines in a variable! That's perfect.

Comment: To answer the "why bash" question, these students come in with zero CLI experience, so I try to get them in front of a command prompt as much as possible. Again, Python would probably work pretty well, and I may convert to that when I have more time. Or hell, even C. With C, I could setuid it and read from my own dir with .txt sources.